# Difference between put(...) and append(...) for a SparseArray?

Tags: android, append, put

I just want to know what is the difference between `put(...)` and `append(...)` for a SparseArray ?

From the official documentation :

- `append(...)` : Puts a key/value pair into the array, optimizing for the case where the key is greater than all existing keys in the array.
- `put(...)` : Adds a mapping from the specified key to the specified value, replacing the previous mapping from the specified key if there was one.

But I just do not understand :s

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentially they do the same thing.
In fact the code for append uses **put**:

```
 /**
 * Puts a key/value pair into the array, optimizing for the case where
 * the key is greater than all existing keys in the array.
 */
public void append(int key, E value) {
    if (mSize != 0 && key <= mKeys[mSize - 1]) {
        **put(key, value);**
        return;
    }

    if (mGarbage && mSize >= mKeys.length) {
        gc();
    }

    int pos = mSize;
    if (pos >= mKeys.length) {
        int n = ArrayUtils.idealIntArraySize(pos + 1);
        int[] nkeys = new int[n];
        Object[] nvalues = new Object[n];
        // Log.e("SparseArray", "grow " + mKeys.length + " to " + n);
        System.arraycopy(mKeys, 0, nkeys, 0, mKeys.length);
        System.arraycopy(mValues, 0, nvalues, 0, mValues.length);
        mKeys = nkeys;
        mValues = nvalues;
    }
    mKeys[pos] = key;
    mValues[pos] = value;
    mSize = pos + 1;
}
```

**So what is the difference?**
As you can see from the source code, if the key is greater than all existing keys in the array, the code will create a new size optimized array, copy all the keys/values into the new array and add the new key at the top of the array.

**When should you use it?**
If your keys are sequential, you get a performance advantage since you know for a fact that the next key you are going to be using is larger than the keys you used before (well, that is what sequential means:-)), so you know that you are going to need to grow the array.
If your keys are not sequential, well in that case you have to "spend" the CPU power every time you add a new key to figure out if the key you are adding requires the code to grow the array or not. A large array with many keys/values and key/value inputs, that can be a bit of a performance degrader.

Comment: "add the new key at the top of the array"? I would call the last entry in an array "bottom".

Answer (score 16):

It appears to me that the documentation is pretty straightforward:

If you add sequential keys, such as 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13..., use `append()`.

If you add non-sequential keys, such as 100, 23, 45, 277, 42..., use `put()`.

There's no reason you can't use `put()` in either scenario, but if you know the keys will be sequential -- for example, while loading data from storage -- then `append()` will give you a performance advantage.

Comment: so im guessing if we want to update a key, put will be the better option ?

Comment: Misleading answer. Answer from yoram givon is much better. you can still use append() even if the keys are not sequential. Just that you won't be able to reap the benefit of it.

Comment: @adnaan.zohran What exactly is supposed to be "misleading" about this answer? It's exactly the same thing, but expressed more briefly.